# Anaconda showing this error , can't train model properly

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
2021-02-03 19:46:53.571084: W tensorflow/stream_executor/gpu/redzone_allocator.cc:314] Internal: Invoking GPU asm compilation is supported on Cuda non-Windows platforms only
Relying on driver to perform ptx compilation.
Modify $PATH to customize ptxas location.
This message will be only logged once.
```

I am getting the above error when I am trying to train my deep nueral network. It doestn't stop training but the first iteration is not working fine. See below:

```
Epoch 1/10
   1/1875 [..............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.3001 - accuracy: 0.1250
WARNING:tensorflow:Callbacks method `on_train_batch_end` is slow compared to the batch time (batch time: 0.0000s vs `on_train_batch_end` time: 0.0116s). Check your callbacks.
```

Help me to fix this error.

I am using tensorflow verson 2.3.0, cuda tool kit version 10.1.243, cudnn version 7.6.5 and my pc has NVDIA GEFORCE RTX 2070 with Super Max-Q design.

Some solutions say to downgrade tensorflow version, but for some projects I need 2.3.0, so please any one solve this error.

Comment: You have a CUDA version and tensorflow version which don't support and haven't been built to include support for your GPU. You probably need a TF version which supports CUDA 11 for this to work

Answer (score 5):

I met the same problem, my TensorFlow version is 2.4.1. with Python 3.9, and cuda 10.1. Luckily, I found a solution by installing the following package,

```
conda install -c conda-forge cudatoolkit-dev
```

The original link is [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/40036).

Answer (score 0):

This is a compatibility issue between your Tensorflow Version, NVIDA driver version, CUDA version, and cuDNN version. For installations with proven hardware and software compatibility use this link: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu

Comment: no, I checked the official website, I installed the compatible versions only

Comment: @SandeepPasumarthi Which NVIDIA gpu are you using?

Comment: NVDIA GEFORCE RTX 2070 with Super MAX-Q design

Comment: and the driver version is 457.20 and contains 2560 cuda cores

Comment: @SandeepPasumarthi Which tensorflow version are you using?

Comment: tensorflow version 2.3.0

Comment: @SandeepPasumarthi are you using tensorflow-2.3.0 or tensorflow_gpu-2.3.0

Comment: Tensorflow 2.3.0 not tensorflow-gpu